# Copying file from DVD fails

Tags: arch-linux, file-copy, dvd

I am running Arch linux on my MacBook (Late 2009 unibody, if it matters). Using the following command, I attempted to copy an ISO that is stored on the disk onto my computer

```
pv /mnt/file.iso > /home/file.iso
```

However, after running this, it stops at 59% and reports the following error

```
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 4296052
```

I tried it again, and the same error occurred. I also tried using `dd`, but the same error eventually occurred there too. The file is ~12gb.

Is this a problem with the DVD, the drive, or is there something else that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the DVD's surface, is the a scratch or has just someone touched it with his sticky fingers? How could you get 12 GB on a DVD?

Answer (score 2):

This read error is likely a problem with the DVD.

Consider using `ddrescue` which can read past the error.  Remember that the error will remain as zero's in the copied image.